# Pod lib lint command cannot find watchos simularor

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, watchos

I am writing library which I am trying to distribute via cocoa pods, but when I run pod lib lint my build fails only for watchOS, it says that can not find watch OS simulator with specific ID, but after that list all simulators and at that list there is a simulator with that ID. Please take a look at image.

[image]

why is this happening and how I can resolve it?

I've tried to keep open that watch os simulator and closed also while I am running pod lib lint command, but same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was introduced with Xcode 14. The CocoaPods tracking issue at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11558.

One workaround is to use Xcode 13.

Comment: Thanks, I also found different solution base on discussion from link.

The problem was that there was a few watch OS simulators which are not used or paired to any device and for some reason that one was chosen when pod lib lint was started. If this script from previous link does not help you can also remove unnecessary simulators from terminal via command:

    xcrun simctl delete unavailable

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing the deployment target to a simulator version you have installed solved the issue. [Here's how to download earlier simulator runtimes.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes)